# Выражение «ничтоже сумняшеся»

Tags: этимология, фразеология, значение-слов

Недавно вспомнилось это выражение. Интересно было бы узнать, каким образом в современном русском языке сумело сохраниться столь архаичное выражение и, главное, что оно точно означает?
Мне кажется, что "нисколько не сомневаясь", но я-то как раз сомневаюсь.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нашел в сети очень хороший ответ на Ваш вопрос :

> ... пояснить значение оборота «ничтоже сумняся», рассказать, чем оно отличается от «ничтоже сумняшеся», и указать, в каких случаях его следует употреблять.
>
> Эти слова – заимствование из церковно-славянского языка, цитата из Евангелия, сохранившая своё оригинальное звучание, в отличие от многих других новозаветных крылатых выражений. Оба варианта: и «сумняся», и «сумняшеся» – верны и являются деепричастиями от глагола «сумнятеся» (сомневаться). Слово «ничтоже» означает «ничуть, нисколько». Употребление этого архаичного выражения вне исходного контекста в речи современного человека (взамен аналогичного и более уместного оборота «ничуть не сомневаясь») делает его ироническим.
>
> И в самом деле, так говорят, обычно, чтобы подчеркнуть легкомысленность действий и их необдуманную поспешность и тем самым подготовить слушателя к их печальным последствиям. Во время своего путешествия из Сахалина я достаточно привык к туманам и свежим ветрам и потому смотрю теперь на Чёрное море свысока и во время качки обедаю ничтоже сумняся (А. Чехов).
>
> Кстати, этот оборот даёт понять, что в древнеславянском языке не было двойного отрицания. Согласно нынешним правилам правильно было бы говорить «ничтоже не сумняся». Вероятно, именно это обстоятельство и смущает некоторых людей, которые считают, что фраза «ничтоже сумняшеся» тождественна «немного сомневаясь», в то время как в ней не допускается абсолютно никакого сомнения.
> [Ссылка](http://newslab.ru/blog/177377)

Answer (score 1):

Уточню, что выражение представляет собой цитату из Послания Иакова 1:6. В Синодальном переводе текст звучит так: "Но да просит с верою, нимало не сомневаясь, потому что сомневающийся подобен морской волне, ветром поднимаемой и развеваемой".

Перевод Библии на русский язык был издан и получил распространение только в XIX веке. И даже после этого перевод на церковнославянский использовался довольно долго. Тот же Чехов в своём рассказе "Мужики" пишет, что на всю деревню было одно Евангелие, причём не русском, а на церковнославянском языке. Поэтому некоторые библейские выражения и по сей день употребляются именно в церковнославянском варианте ("не хлебом единым", "не сотвори себе кумира", "на круги своя", "за други своя", "ищите и обрящете", "живый в помощи", "иже еси на небесех", "на злобу дня" и т.д.).